# How to get typescript error when using undeclared fields in useState's dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Ideally I'd like to know why ts throws no errors in the case below and if there's a way to fix that so that it works as expected.

I'm expecting a typescript error when trying to update some state via `useState`'s dispatcher callback, but nothing happens. This appears to be valid:

```
  type State = {
    age?: number;
  };

  const [, setState] = useState<State>();

  setState((prev) => {
    // const copy = { ...prev };
    // this is a ts error;
    // copy.name = "scotty";
    // this is not
    return { ...prev, name: "scotty" };
  });
```

I'm expecting ts to throw an error on the extra undeclared field `name` (I could specify the return type, but I shouldn't have to because the dispatch's argument should be inferred `((prevState: S) => S)`).

How can I type this such that I get the ts error I'm expecting; the only allowable fields for this update should be the fields defined/of type in `State`.

Most importantly why doesn't this work?

Heres a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-ts-errorless-r8ryb) to play with.

Comment: In general Typescript does not consider extra properties to be a problem.  If an object fits `{age?: number}` then it's a `State`.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript errors come from the typescript linter which is defined by the `tsconfig.json` file that you'd commonly put at the root of your project.

And you did not include any `tsconfig.json` to your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-kowalevski-um7z6?file=/src/App.tsx:108-361)

Please add this `tsconfig.json` ad your root folder in order to get your expected lint error :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

After adding this to your codesandbox I got the error as expected :

[image: ts linter error]

Now as you can see in this error, it still allows you to add the `name` property where it should not.

For this you can just add the return type to you SetStateAction :

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    
    setState((prev):State => { // <=== Add the State return type here
      // const copy = { ...prev };
      // copy.name = "scotty";
      return { ...prev, name: "scotty" };
    });
  }, []);
```

One line solution :

```js
  useEffect(() => setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, age: 9 })), []);
```

Comment: Hey I updated the codesandbox with my tsconfig. This doesn't solve my problem/explain why ts throws no errors where I expect it too. In your example the error is expected because age is not an optional type and it is not provided. I want it to error on the extra field `name` because it's not defined as a `State` type.

Comment: Also updated the code snippets to highlight that by making `age` optional.